# Nuclear fission in the Sun

Tags: nuclear-physics, astrophysics, estimation, sun

The Sun's energy comes primarily from fusion of light elements in its core.

It is estimated that a very small fraction of mass of the Sun (~$10^{-12}$ times the abundance of hydrogen) is [uranium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uranium) (both [235](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uranium-235) and [238](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uranium-238) isotopes). But given the huge mass of the sun (~$2*10^{30}$ kg), the mass of uranium in sun will come to around $2*10^{18}$ kg, which is again a significant quantity.

Since uranium is heavier compared to other elements in the Sun, I reckon that most of it will sink to core or at least be concentrated in inner regions of the Sun. This uranium would undergo spontaneous fission, but further, nuclear fusion taking place in the core releases a large amount of neutrons every second (which can cause fission of uranium nearby, similar to what happens in a multistage thermonuclear weapon).

Is there fission of uranium taking place in sun as well? What percent of Sun's energy output can be attributed to fission?

Comment: As you ask about the energy output of the sun by fission (of Uranium & consorts), I guess you are supposing this would be a *source* of energy. This is not the case. Any Uranium, very short lived in the heat and bombardment with protons and other particles, would have to be built up at first, drawing energy. So the energy via the Uranium route does not really come from Uranium fission, but is only delayed by creating Uranium as a first step.

Comment: @GyroGearloose …The sun's not big enough to make uranium, is it? Don't you need a supernova (kilo-, hyper-, uber-utlra-nova, whatever) for that?

Comment: @WillChen it looks like I really overestimated the power of our sun, one, in creating heavy nuclei, and, two, in destroying them. Are there any processes in our sun that would accelerate the decay of uranium significantly?

Comment: @GyroGearloose Not an expert and haven't really looked into it recently, but IIRC there are not really any parameters that can affect the speed of radioactive decay. Other than radioactive decay, fissioning induced by free neutrons would destroy it too, but as ProfRob's answer points out, those should be exceedingly rare in the proton-heavy Sun.

Comment: @WillChen I was thinking of high energy protons, like those that create diprotons and deuterium, that also might smash against any uranium and change or destroy it. But thinking twice, the outer layers of the sun might be too cool for that.

Comment: @GyroGearloose From what I could gather, the Uranium in the sun is not produced in the sun itself but from supernova and neutron star merger processes which are hypothesized to take place much before the formation of our solar system...the nebula that resulted from these processes contained the Uranium and other heavy elements, which eventually coalesced to form sun and other planets.

Comment: @WillChen yes you are right..the most acceptable hypothesis currently is that it was produced in a neutron star merger or supernova event about 6.6 billion years ago....however it is further speculated that this was not the only event that generated the heavy elements, but only one of many

Answer (score 14):

There must be spontaneous fission of uranium taking place in the Sun. But the long half-life of this process, combined with the very low abundance of uranium means that **fission** is a totally negligible fraction ($\sim 10^{-26}$) of the average solar output. The fission process is spontaneous rather than induced by neutrons, because there is no significant source of free neutrons in the Sun.

The energy produced by **radioactive decay** of uranium is far larger, because the lifetimes for radioactive decay are shorter, although the total output is still negligible - a fraction of about $1.4\times 10^{-10}$ of the solar output, averaged over its lifetime.

**Details**

**Spontaneous Fission**

There will of course be some fission taking place in the Sun. That fission would have to be spontaneous since there is no plentiful supply of free neutrons inside the Sun. The spontaneous fission process itself is so slow, and the fissile material so sparse that any kind of "chain reaction" is not possible.

The Uranium does not get concentrated significantly towards the core. That is because the Sun is sufficiently well mixed and turbulent that any diffusion processes are rather slow. [Asplund et al. (2020)](https://www.aanda.org/articles/aa/full_html/2021/09/aa40445-21/aa40445-21.html) estimate the *primordial* abundance fraction of uranium, and accounts both for its half-life to radiactive decay and for a modest amount (only 0.06 dex) of concentration towards the centre over its lifetime. They report initial fractional abundances (by number, with respect to hydrogen) of $10^{-12.65}$ and $10^{-12.16}$ for $^{235}U$ and $^{238}U$ respectively.

The primordial mass fraction of hydrogen is estimated to be 71%. Thus if we take 1 kg of the primordial solar material, then it contains about $4.25\times 10^{26}$ hydrogen atoms, $9.5\times 10^{13}$ $^{235}$U atoms and $2.9\times10^{14}$ $^{238}$U atoms.

The [spontaneous fission decay constants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spontaneous_fission#Spontaneous_fission_rate), $\lambda$, of $^{235}$U and $^{238}$U can be calculated as $2.0\times10^{-19}$ year$^{-1}$   and $8.3\times 10^{-17}$ yr$^{-1}$ respectively.

The number of spontaneous fissions that have taken place over the lifetime of the Sun will be
$$N_0[1 - \exp(-\lambda\ \tau)] \simeq N_0\lambda\ \tau\ ,$$
(assuming $\lambda\ \tau \ll 1$), where $N_0$ is the initial number of nuclei and $\tau$ is the age of the Sun ($\tau \simeq 4.57\times 10^{9}$ years). This is an upper limit because the uranium nuclei will be decaying other than by fission on shorter lifetimes. Each spontaneous fission ultimately releases about [200 MeV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spontaneous_fission) of energy.

Taking the mass of the Sun as $2\times 10^{30}$ kg, then the total number of decays is $3.8\times 10^{25}$ and $4.8\times 10^{28}$ for $^{235}$U and $^{238}$U respectively (i.e. the contribution from the light isotope is negligible because of its lower abundance and slower spontaneous fission rate). This number should probably be reduced by a small factor because the $^{238}$U has a radioactive decay half-life roughly equal to the age of the Sun.

The total energy released **by U fission** is therefore about $10^{31}$ MeV or $1.5\times 10^{18}$ J over the lifetime of the Sun at an average power of $\sim 10$ Watts.

This is roughly the amount of energy that the Sun releases in 4 billionths of a second!

**Radioactive decay**

Far more energy is generated from the radioactive decay of uranium into lead isotopes. The rate-determining step here is the half-life of the initial decays of the uranium isotopes ($\lambda = 9.8\times10^{-10}$ year$^{-1}$, and $1.55\times 10^{-10}$ year$^{-1}$ for $^{235}$U and $^{238}U$ respectively.)

The number of decays is given by the equation above (the approximation cannot be used here), thus 99% of the $^{235}$U and about 50% of the $^{238}$U has decayed.

Each decay chain (to lead) releases about 100 MeV of energy. Thus the total energy released by both isotopes is $(0.99\times 9.5\times 10^{13} + 0.5\times 2.9\times 10^{14})\times 2\times 10^{30} \times 100$ MeV $= 7.6\times 10^{33}$ J - an average of $5\times 10^{16}$ W over the solar lifetime, or about $1.4\times 10^{-10}$ of its total output, with the fraction declining from an initially higher value to a value lower than this today (as all of the $^{235}$U has decayed).

Comment: I tried to estimate free neutrons in the Sun, see https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/190220/free-neutrons-in-the-suns-core/742155#742155 . It is very rough but says maybe there are $10^{38}$ neutrons. You are estimating, I think, $10^{45}$ uranium nuclei so maybe those neutrons are enough to promote the fission rate above the spontaneous decay rate.

Comment: I think you significantly underestimated. 60kg U can give [over 2 TJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_weapon_yield) in a nuclear bomb. Earth's crust [is estimated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uranium#Biotic_and_abiotic) to have $10^{17}$ kg of U. That gives some ten orders of magnitude more energy that you estimate for the Sun...

Comment: @Mithoron can you point me to exactly where that figure is given for a fission weapon, it is hard to find. I find that mass of U in the Sun to be about $3\times 10^{20}$ kg.

Comment: It's seventh row in the table. Well, my ballpark estimate is, if about $10^{-12}$ of Sun is U, than output from it should be about $10^{-15}$ of total output (give or take an order of mag. or two).

Comment: That would be some 0.1 TW or so. 10W is really tiny - one RTG can produce much more, even if for a relatively short time.

Comment: @Mithoron the 7th row of the table says that the Ivy King bomb produced 2100 TJ (not 2 TJ) from 60 kg of hightly enriched uranium. Thus $1.8 \times 10^{26}$ nuclei, producing an average of just 73 MeV each, if they we all to fission. I used 200 MeV.  Perhaps you've forgotten the factor that hardly any of the uranium undergoes *spontaneous* fission  in the lifetime of the Sun?

Comment: Oh, it's this comma vs dot thing, sorry, but that's giving 3 orders more! *Most* of U undergoes spontaneous fission in the lifetime of the Sun. Longest half-life of U is "only" 4.5 billion years.

Comment: @Mithoron, that is the half life for radioactive decay. Got it. The question asks specifically about fission - so that it what I gave in my answer. I will add an answer based on radioactive decay which is more significant.

Comment: @AndrewSteane the calculation referred to didn't account for the capture of free neutrons by protons, which I think reduces their numbers by 13 orders of magnitude.